# Keeping only x records of an item in subversion?

Tags: svn

I currently keep an SQL Dump of my db with each commit. However, the whole dump is stored each time, and is taking up a lot of space. Is there any way to set it so that subversion only keeps the last, say, 5 commits of the .sql file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion isn't really designed to "forget" history. Even the [procedure for getting rid of any traces of a file](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#removal) in a Subversion repository is generally to svndump the entire thing and then run it through a filter while re-importing it to a new repo.

You're probably best off (if you can't stand the space usage) just keeping DB backups somewhere else, outside of version control.

Answer (score 2):

SVN does not store the whole file in every commit. It only stores the diffs between commits.